# Evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left( \sqrt[3]{x^3+1} -\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you help to evaluate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left( \sqrt[3]{x^3+1} -\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}\right)?$$
I tried all methods I know of to no avail

Comment: Hint: The answer is $0$.

Comment: What methods do you know of? (hint: try factoring $x$ out of each root term and then use the binomial theorem.)

Comment: I tried it but still ended up with ∞×0

Comment: @Steven Stadincki can you provide more help as I get stuck after binomial theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3 + 1} - \sqrt[4]{x^4 + 1}\right)} &= \lim_{x \to \infty}{x\left(\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{x^3}} - \sqrt[4]{1 + \frac{1}{x^4}}\right)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}{x\left(1 + \frac{1}{3x^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right) -  1 - \frac{1}{4x^4} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^8}\right)\right)}\\
& =\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{3x^2} - \frac{1}{4x^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^5} \right)}\\
& = 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

let $x=\frac{1}{t}$ then $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{{(1+t^3)}^{1/3}-{(1+t^4)}^{1/4}}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(1+\frac{t^3}{3}...).-(1+\frac{t^4}{4}...)}{t}=?.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor series we have that for any $\alpha > 0$,  when $x\to 0$
$$ (1+x)^{\alpha}= 1 + \alpha x + o(x). $$
Then when $x \to + \infty $
$$ (1+x^3)^{1/3} - (1+x^4)^{1/4}= x\left( 1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^{1/3} - x\left( 1+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^{1/4} =\frac{1}{3x^2} - \frac{1}{4x^3} + o \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right) = \frac{1}{3x^2} + o \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right).$$
So $ [(1+x^3)^{1/3} - (1+x^4)^{1/4} ] \to 0$ when $x \to + \infty $.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 + 1} - \sqrt[4]{x^4 + 1}} 
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3 + 1}-x + x- \sqrt[4]{x^4 + 1}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{x^3+1-x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}^2+x\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}+x^2}+\frac{x^4-x^4-1}{x^3+x^2\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}+x\sqrt{x^4+1}+\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}^3}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}^2+x\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}+x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3+x^2\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}+x\sqrt{x^4+1}+\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}^3}}\\
&=0-0\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Answer (score -2):

That's equivalent to $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(x^3+1)^{1/3} -(x^4+1)^{1/4}}{x},$$ to which you may apply L'hopital.